# Grafana receives epoch timestamp 1 hour ahead from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2014, grafana

Data source is SQL Server 2014 (Read only). Grafana v8.2.1.

Column is `changeDate datetime2(7)`.
I'm using DBeaver configured in CET (I am in UTC+1 timezone) and it displays:
Actual UTC time of the event: `2022-01-27 12:47:09`

Cell value:    `2022-01-27 13:47:09` (CET, UTC +1)

`2022-01-27T12:47:09.784Z` (value displayed as source code in ISO8601 format, so UTC)

Everything seems ok, it´s the actual time. Then I check the received data in Grafana configured in CET (UTC +1) time zone.

(raw data) `1643291229000` or GMT(UTC): `2022-01-27 13:47:09` (shift of +1 hour)

Displayed as UTC + 1: `2022-01-27 14:47:09`

You can see that the Epoch timestamp is 1 hour ahead.

My query is quite simple: `SELECT changeDate as time (...)`
I am not able to use `AT TIME ZONE` in SQL Server 2014.

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: No, it's not 1 hour ahead. It's exactly what 13:47 UTC would look at UTC+1. The conversion was performed by Grafana anyway, not SQL Server. If you care about offsets you should use `datetimeoffset` but in this case, all properly configured applications would display the same time

Comment: SQL Server or JSON don't deal with UNIX timestamps anyway. Almost all major databases (except SQLite) have proper date types. In JSON, the actual date literal standard is the ISO8601 format. The actual storage format shouldn't matter and most likely *isn't* the same as a Unix Timestamp.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then, the data is stored in UTC or in UTC +1?
Why if I display database values as source code/json it is 2022-01-27T12:47:09.784Z (I guess this is UTC) ?

Comment: You tell us. You're the one storing the data. Without the offset in `datetimeoffset` you can only *assume* that the date is stored as UTC. What you described suggest the date is stored as UTC and properly displayed as UTC+1. UTC means an offset of `+00:00`. UTC+1 means an offset of `+01:00`. The time `13:00+00` is `14:00 +01:00`

Comment: What's the actual problem? Since you configured Grafana to display CET times, why do expect different British winter time? 12pm in London is 13:00 in Vienna. If you store a value as 12pm London, every application configured to display Vienna time would show 13:00

Comment: stored:  `2022-01-27T12:47:09.784Z` (UTC)
displayed in database client dbeaver: `2022-01-27 13:47:09` (CET, UTC+1)
in Grafana with UCT+1: `2022-01-27 14:47:09`

Comment: That's neither a Grafana nor a dbeaver bug. You configured Grafana to handle times as UTC+1 while dbeaver was left to assume they are local. Again, **nothing says this is UTC** except your assumptions. Applications can assume anything they want - that this is local time, UTC, or Pacific time. There's simply no timezone information. Only `datetimeoffset` includes an actual offset

Comment: Then the Grafana timezone setting (that It is configured as UTC+1) is for the data timezone or for the displaying date format?

Comment: Do you refer to the `default_timezone` setting? That's the display timezone. Not format. The [Change Grafana default timezone](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/preferences/change-grafana-timezone/) page explains that `By default, Grafana uses the timezone in your web browser. However, you can override this setting at the server, organization, team, or individual user level.`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thnk u very much for your time. I still don't get why `2022-01-27T12:47:09.784Z` is received  in Grafana as  `1643291229000` or `2022-01-27 13:47:09 UTC`

Comment: Because they're identical. `Z` is the same as `UTC+0` or just `UTC`. [From the Wikipedia article on ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)) `If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "T0930Z"`

Comment: From the [UTC article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones) `The time zone using UTC is sometimes denoted UTC±00:00 or by the letter Z—a reference to the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which has been denoted by a Z since about 1950.`

Comment: I understand that, but why `12:47:00Z` UTC+0 in the database, then is `13:47:00` UTC+0 on grafana (and `14:47:00` UTC+1)

Comment: That sounds like a double misconfiguration. Perhaps the application code that stored the JSON date into SQL Server stored it as local time? That's why I repeated so many times that you can only *assume* what the timezone is with `datetime2`, that you *must* use `datetimeoffset` if you really care about timezones. Or make absolutely sure everyone, every application, handles timezones the same way. In this case one application was configured to store UTC as local while another assumed the timezone is UTC and tried to convert again

Comment: I know for sure that  the stored value `12:47:00Z` is UTC+0. But I only have Read access, so I can not change it to datetimeoffset

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix it with this query, but it is not the most stylish solution.

```
DECLARE @offset int = datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getdate());
SELECT
  DATEADD(hour, - @offset, changeDate) as time,
  column2 as value
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
  changeDate BETWEEN  DATEADD(hour, @offset, CAST($__timeFrom() AS DATETIME2)) AND DATEADD(hour, @offset, CAST($__timeTo() AS DATETIME2))
```